# Java - Discovering Raspberry Pi hostname - works on windows but not on Android

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hello :) I use this script to discover hostnames on my network. It works perfectly when I run it on Windows, allowing me to see all of my active devices, including my Raspberry Pi 3 b+ Stretch (which is the desired target).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("IP Address:- " + inetAddress.getHostAddress());
            System.out.println("Host Name:- " + inetAddress.getHostName());
            InetAddress ipd = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.1");
            byte[] ip = ipd.getAddress();
            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
                ip[3] = (byte)i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                System.out.println(address);
                System.out.println(address.getHostName());
                if (address.getHostName().toLowerCase().contains("raspberry")) {
                    System.out.println("PI FOUND!!!");
                    System.out.println(address.getHostName());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    }
}
```

However, when I run the script on either of my two android phones (Samsung J7 and Nokia 6.1) I cannot see any of the devices on my network, including the Pi.

If I run the script directly from the Pi it identifies as the loopback localhost ip of 127.0.0.1 and then cannot find itself as it scans through the IPs of my network. I believe this has something to do with DNS settings but then why does it work from my windows PC when its using the same DNS servers?

One note: It works for my colleague. He has exactly the same setup (same Raspberry model, Raspbian image and phones).

Is there something wrong in the code? Is there something on Android that prevents it from working properly? My guess is that it could be related to my router settings but then why does it work when I run it on Windows?

Thank you in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**: I was able to run the cordova app through Android Studio. I only set it to read the first 5 IP addresses (i.e. 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.5). The Pi was on 10.0.0.5. Here is the catlog:

> 2019-02-07 19:03:46.035 18008-18008/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess -
>   Process is Whitelisted 2019-02-07 19:03:46.036 18008-18008/?
>   E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas 2019-02-07 19:03:46.036 18008-18008/?
>   E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File -
>   /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
>   2019-02-07 19:03:46.039 18008-18008/? W/SELinux: SELinux
>   selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2], 
>   Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SAMSUNG-SM-J727A_8.1.0_0004, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0
>   1] 2019-02-07 19:03:46.040 18008-18008/? I/SELinux: SELinux:
>   seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768,
>   pkgname=io.cordova.hellocordova  2019-02-07 19:03:46.044 18008-18008/?
>   I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 2019-02-07 19:03:46.107
>   18008-18008/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled:
>   cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
>   2019-02-07 19:03:46.108 18008-18008/? D/ActivityThread: Added
>   TimaKeyStore provider 2019-02-07 19:03:46.211
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/CordovaLog: Changing log level
>   to DEBUG(3) 2019-02-07 19:03:46.211
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova
>   native platform version 7.1.4 is starting 2019-02-07 19:03:46.211
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaActivity:
>   CordovaActivity.onCreate() 2019-02-07 19:03:46.232
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/WebViewFactory: Loading
>   com.android.chrome version 71.0.3578.99 (code 357809902) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.295 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/cr_LibraryLoader:
>   Time to load native libraries: 7 ms (timestamps 2174-2181) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.341 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium:
>   [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level =
>   0, default verbosity = 0 2019-02-07 19:03:46.342
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected
>   native library version number "71.0.3578.99", actual native library
>   version number "71.0.3578.99" 2019-02-07 19:03:46.350
>   18008-18033/io.cordova.hellocordova W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new
>   ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome,
>   sandboxed = true 2019-02-07 19:03:46.360
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing
>   chromium process, singleProcess=false 2019-02-07 19:03:46.366
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova W/ResourceType: Failure getting
>   entry for 0x7f120515 (t=17 e=1301) (error -2147483647) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.591 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by:
>   samsung 2019-02-07 19:03:46.608 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/PluginManager: init() 2019-02-07 19:03:46.617
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>>
>   loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 2019-02-07 19:03:46.629
>   18008-18060/io.cordova.hellocordova W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH
>   permission 2019-02-07 19:03:46.631 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/CordovaActivity: Started the activity. 2019-02-07 19:03:46.635
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 2019-02-07 19:03:46.639
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the
>   activity. 2019-02-07 19:03:46.655 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline 2019-02-07 19:03:46.663
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport: Input channel
>   constructed: fd=127 2019-02-07 19:03:46.664
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: setView =
>   DecorView@8d5f51[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.681 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaWebViewImpl:
>   onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.687 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/InputMethodManager:
>   Not IME target window, ignoring 2019-02-07 19:03:46.698
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime audio/x-ima 2019-02-07 19:03:46.728
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime audio/mpeg-L1 2019-02-07 19:03:46.729
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime audio/mpeg-L2 2019-02-07 19:03:46.743
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime audio/x-ms-wma 2019-02-07 19:03:46.746
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   2019-02-07 19:03:46.772 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/Surface:
>   sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : true, logging : 0 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.774 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={valid=true
>   3339589632} changed=true 2019-02-07 19:03:46.776
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4 2019-02-07 19:03:46.777
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
>   2019-02-07 19:03:46.781 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package :
>   io.cordova.hellocordova 2019-02-07 19:03:46.783
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/mali_winsys: EGLint
>   new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.783 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xdd00c390, 0xc70e1808 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.809 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/vndksupport:
>   Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so
>   from current namespace instead of sphal namespace. 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.827 18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities:
>   Unsupported mime video/mp43 2019-02-07 19:03:46.841
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized
>   profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es 2019-02-07 19:03:46.842
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized
>   profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es 2019-02-07 19:03:46.842
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized
>   profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es 2019-02-07 19:03:46.847
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime video/wvc1 2019-02-07 19:03:46.850
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime video/wvc1 2019-02-07 19:03:46.874
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/libGLESv2: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC
>   are not allowed for Package : io.cordova.hellocordova 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.877 18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities:
>   Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7 2019-02-07 19:03:46.882
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported
>   mime video/x-ms-wmv8 2019-02-07 19:03:46.887
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT:
>   frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0,
>   0) or=1 2019-02-07 19:03:46.887 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   2019-02-07 19:03:46.895 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@b609fcb nm :
>   io.cordova.hellocordova ic=null 2019-02-07 19:03:46.896
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - Id : 0 2019-02-07 19:03:46.896
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus 2019-02-07
>   19:03:46.911 18008-18022/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport:
>   Input channel constructed: fd=107 2019-02-07 19:03:46.922
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/InputMethodManager: Starting
>   input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ad613a8 nm :
>   io.cordova.hellocordova ic=null 2019-02-07 19:03:46.923
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - Id : 0 2019-02-07 19:03:46.924
>   18008-18078/io.cordova.hellocordova I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported
>   profile 4 for video/mp4v-es 2019-02-07 19:03:47.211
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/JsMessageQueue: Set native->JS
>   mode to EvalBridgeMode 2019-02-07 19:03:48.086
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/SystemWebChromeClient:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js: Line 1 : null
>   2019-02-07 19:03:48.086 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "null", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js (1) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:48.473 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/PluginManager:
>   THREAD WARNING: exec() call to networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress
>   blocked the main thread for 20ms. Plugin should use
>   CordovaInterface.getThreadPool(). 2019-02-07 19:03:48.483
>   18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: networkinterface1017920643
>       Result was: "Invalid action" 2019-02-07 19:03:48.565 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
>   2019-02-07 19:03:48.583 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ScrollView: initGoToTop 2019-02-07 19:03:48.606
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=30KB, data=29KB 2019-02-07 19:03:48.606
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: After code cache
>   collection, code=30KB, data=29KB 2019-02-07 19:03:48.607
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Increasing code cache
>   capacity to 128KB 2019-02-07 19:03:48.625
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport: Input channel
>   constructed: fd=144 2019-02-07 19:03:48.626
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: setView =
>   DecorView@f03ec4c[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false 2019-02-07
>   19:03:48.646 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   2019-02-07 19:03:48.690 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/Surface:
>   sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : true, logging : 0 2019-02-07
>   19:03:48.692 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[18,475][702,853] result=0x7 surface={valid=true
>   3280465920} changed=true 2019-02-07 19:03:48.695
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/mali_winsys: EGLint
>   new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [812x506]-format:1 2019-02-07
>   19:03:48.695 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xc4305530, 0xc387f008 2019-02-07
>   19:03:48.716 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView:  onsize
>   change changed  2019-02-07 19:03:48.717
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView:  onsize change
>   changed  2019-02-07 19:03:48.721 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   2019-02-07 19:03:48.756 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT:
>   frame=Rect(18, 475 - 702, 853) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0,
>   0) or=1 2019-02-07 19:03:48.778 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>   2019-02-07 19:03:49.562 18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote:
>   Do partial code cache collection, code=42KB, data=55KB 2019-02-07
>   19:03:49.563 18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: After code
>   cache collection, code=42KB, data=55KB 2019-02-07 19:03:49.563
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Increasing code cache
>   capacity to 256KB 2019-02-07 19:03:49.565
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB
>   to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
>   2019-02-07 19:03:49.940 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.005 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@dd9a47f[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.053 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin:
>   Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.1" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.056 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.2" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.058 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.3" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.060 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.4" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.062 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.5" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.472 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "/10.0.0.254" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.476 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send
>   a second callback for ID: Hello1017920644
>       Result was: "IP Address:127.0.0.1// Host Name:localhost" 2019-02-07 19:03:50.476 18008-18121/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Hello.greet blocked
>   the main thread for 427ms. Plugin should use
>   CordovaInterface.getThreadPool(). 2019-02-07 19:03:50.478
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/SystemWebChromeClient:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js: Line 1 : No
>   valid IP address identified 2019-02-07 19:03:50.478
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "No
>   valid IP address identified", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js (1) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.524 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView:
>   initGoToTop 2019-02-07 19:03:50.541
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
>   2019-02-07 19:03:50.576 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=144 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.577 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: setView =
>   DecorView@4388549[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.594 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   2019-02-07 19:03:50.637 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/Surface:
>   sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : true, logging : 0 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.638 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[18,475][702,853] result=0x7 surface={valid=true
>   3271704576} changed=true 2019-02-07 19:03:50.641
>   18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/mali_winsys: EGLint
>   new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [812x506]-format:1 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.641 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xc43054b8, 0xc3024008 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.662 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView:  onsize
>   change changed  2019-02-07 19:03:50.663
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/ScrollView:  onsize change
>   changed  2019-02-07 19:03:50.670 18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=92KB, data=108KB
>   2019-02-07 19:03:50.670 18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote:
>   After code cache collection, code=88KB, data=75KB 2019-02-07
>   19:03:50.672 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   2019-02-07 19:03:50.698 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT:
>   frame=Rect(18, 475 - 702, 853) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0,
>   0) or=1 2019-02-07 19:03:50.713 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>   2019-02-07 19:03:52.360 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0 2019-02-07
>   19:03:52.448 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1 2019-02-07
>   19:03:52.489 18008-18092/io.cordova.hellocordova D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglDestroySurface = 0xc43054b8, 0xc3024000 2019-02-07 19:03:52.489
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@8df3f50[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   2019-02-07 19:03:52.489 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/InputEventReceiver: channel '1942219
>   io.cordova.hellocordova/io.cordova.hellocordova.MainActivity (client)'
>   ~ Disposing input event receiver. 2019-02-07 19:03:52.489
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputEventReceiver: channel
>   '1942219 io.cordova.hellocordova/io.cordova.hellocordova.MainActivity
>   (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver. 2019-02-07 19:03:52.502
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport: Input channel
>   destroyed: fd=144 2019-02-07 19:03:52.504
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/SystemWebChromeClient:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js: Line 1 :
>   /10.0.0.0 2019-02-07 19:03:52.505 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "/10.0.0.0", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js (1) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:52.506 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/SystemWebChromeClient:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js: Line 1 :
>   http://10.0.0.0:3000 2019-02-07 19:03:52.506
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)]
>   "http://10.0.0.0:3000", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js (1) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:52.512 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/ViewRootImpl@a469c78[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   2019-02-07 19:03:52.516 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned. 2019-02-07
>   19:03:52.517 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaWebViewImpl:
>   onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/#/main/login) 2019-02-07
>   19:03:53.391 18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Do partial
>   code cache collection, code=125KB, data=110KB 2019-02-07 19:03:53.391
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: After code cache
>   collection, code=125KB, data=110KB 2019-02-07 19:03:53.392
>   18008-18014/io.cordova.hellocordova I/zygote: Increasing code cache
>   capacity to 512KB 2019-02-07 19:04:22.360
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova V/InputMethodManager: Starting
>   input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5fb2d05 nm :
>   io.cordova.hellocordova ic=null 2019-02-07 19:04:22.360
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - Id : 0 2019-02-07 19:04:22.360
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova I/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus 2019-02-07
>   19:04:22.362 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport:
>   Input channel constructed: fd=137 2019-02-07 19:04:22.362
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/InputTransport: Input channel
>   destroyed: fd=107 2019-02-07 19:04:22.736
>   18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova D/CordovaActivity: Paused the
>   activity. 2019-02-07 19:04:22.757 18008-18008/io.cordova.hellocordova
>   D/CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.

Comment: How is your Windows computer physically connected to your network?

Comment: @chrylis LAN cable.

Comment: In that case, it's very likely that your AP is isolating wireless clients from the rest of the network. You might check your Wi-Fi settings on your router and see if it says something like "client isolation" or "privacy mode".

Comment: @chrylis - I do not believe either client isolation or privacy mode is enabled on my router. Plus, I can use IP scanning apps like Fing and Network IP Scan without any issues. Could I use apps like those if AP/client isolation or privacy mode was enabled?

Comment: Probably not. Now that I look again, though, it seems that you have a hard-coded IP address in this script. Does that actually match your configuration?

Comment: @chrylis - The IP 10.0.0.1 is the proper default gateway IP for my network, which the phone is connected to. I should mention that this java plugin is being used by a cordova app. While trying to debug today with Android Studio I did get the following error:

Comment: 2019-02-07 16:28:04.709 15375-15516/io.cordova.hellocordova W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Hello.greet blocked the main thread for 9929ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
2019-02-07 16:28:04.714 15375-15375/io.cordova.hellocordova D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/main.12e606c81a2773901da4.js: Line 1 : No valid IP address identified